# Function using Array. Why is variable undefined?

Tags: arrays, function, xhtml

This is my first crack at using Arrays.  I have to create an array that stores credit prices for student type (in-state, out-of-state, and international) and another that stores tuition cost for Full-time, Part-Time, and overloaded schedules.

I am having problems creating the function.  I thought I had a decent grasp on it, but my calcCost variable is showing as undefined.  Any advice is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!--Document Head-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <!--Title Element-->
        <title>Greendale Community College</title>
        <!--Style Element-->
        <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: white;
        }
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Impact;
            color: green;
        }

    p {
        font-size: 36px;
        color: green;
    }
    </style>
<!--Script Element-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    /* ]]> */
    // Created function to calculate tuition cost
    var creditCostArray = new Array(3);
    creditCost[0] = 302.00;
    creditCost[1] = 452.00;
    creditCost[2] = 588.00;

    var tuitionCostArray = new Array(3);
    tuitionCost[0] = 3619.00;
    tuitionCost[1] = 5429.00;
    tuitionCost[2] = 7057.00;

    function calcTuition(studentRes) {
        var creditTotal = document.getElementsByName("numCredits")[0].value;
        console.log(creditTotal);
        if (studentRes == "i")
            if (creditTotal < 12)
                calcCost = creditCost[0] * parseInt(creditTotal);
        tuitionTotal = "Student is an Part-Time, In-State Residency taking " + creditTotal + "Credits, Tuition Total is " + calcCost;
        return tuitionTotal;
    }

</script>
</head>
<!--Body Element-->
<body>
    <!--Heading Element-->
    <h1>Greendale Community College</h1>
    <center><img src="greendale.jpg" alt="greendale" width="512" height="256"/></center>
    <h2 align="center">Tuition Calculator</h2>
    <!--Form-->
    <form name="tuitionCalculator" action="" method="get">
    <h2>Semester</h2>
    <h3>(choose a semester)</h3>
        <!--Radio Buttons to Choose Semester-->
        <input type="radio" name="semesterFall" /> Fall 2018 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="semesterSpring" /> Spring 2018 <br />
        <input type="radio" name="semesterSummer" /> Summer 2018 <br />
    <h2>Residency</h2>
    <h3>(choose your residency)</h3>
        <!--Radio Buttons to Choose Residency-->
        <input type="radio" name="residency" value="i" onclick="calcTuition('i')"/> In-State <br />
        <input type="radio" name="residency" value="o" onclick="calcTuition('o')" /> Out-of-State <br />
        <input type="radio" name="residency" value="x" onclick="calcTuition('x')"/> International <br />
    <h2>Credits</h2>
    <h3>(enter your number of credits)</h3>
        <!--Text Box-->
        <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="numCredits" /><br />
        <!--Button to Calculate Tuition-->
        <input type="button" onclick="window.alert(calcTuition())" value="Calculate Your Tuition" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where did you declare your calcCost?

Comment: 1. `creditCost` is not defined. 2. `tuitionCost` is not defined.

Comment: Like I commented on your previous question, radio buttons must be grouped together by giving each one in the group the same name. If you don't, the user can select every radio button (in this case, Fall, Spring and Summer) and will not be able to deselect them. The second group in your source is OK.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `window.alert(calcTuition())`, calcTuition gets no parameter, so your `studentRes` variable is undefined, leading to an undefined cost.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code

1.- You are creating a `creditCostArray` but then you assign values to a completely different object `creditCost` and the same goes for the `tuitionCostArray`

```
// Created function to calculate tuition cost
var creditCostArray = new Array(3);
creditCost[0] = 302.00;
creditCost[1] = 452.00;
creditCost[2] = 588.00;
```

2.- `function calcTuition(studentRes)` needs a parameter and you're calling it without the parameter `window.alert(calcTuition())`

3.- Declare `calcCost` before your if conditions that way you don't get the undefined

Working code will look like this...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* <![CDATA[ */
    /* ]]> */
    // Created function to calculate tuition cost
    var creditCost = new Array(3);
    creditCost[0] = 302.00;
    creditCost[1] = 452.00;
    creditCost[2] = 588.00;

    var tuitionCost = new Array(3);
    tuitionCost[0] = 3619.00;
    tuitionCost[1] = 5429.00;
    tuitionCost[2] = 7057.00;

    function calcTuition(studentRes) {
        var creditTotal = document.getElementsByName("numCredits")[0].value | 0;
        var calcCost = 0;
        console.log(creditTotal);
        if (studentRes == "i")
            if (creditTotal < 12)
                calcCost = creditCost[0] * parseInt(creditTotal);
        tuitionTotal = "Student is an Part-Time, In-State Residency taking " + creditTotal + "Credits, Tuition Total is " + calcCost;
        return tuitionTotal;
    }

</script>
</head>
<!--Body Element-->
<body>
    <!--Heading Element-->
    <h1>Greendale Community College</h1>
    <center><img src="greendale.jpg" alt="greendale" width="512" height="256"/></center>
    <h2 align="center">Tuition Calculator</h2>
    <!--Form-->
    <form name="tuitionCalculator" action="" method="get">
    <h2>Semester</h2>
    <h3>(choose a semester)</h3>
        <!--Radio Buttons to Choose Semester-->
        <input type="radio" id="semesterFall" name="semester" /> Fall 2018 <br />
        <input type="radio" id="semesterSpring" name="semester" /> Spring 2018 <br />
        <input type="radio" id="semesterSummer" name="semester" /> Summer 2018 <br />
    <h2>Residency</h2>
    <h3>(choose your residency)</h3>
        <!--Radio Buttons to Choose Residency-->
        <input type="radio" name="residency" value="i" onclick="calcTuition('i')"/> In-State <br />
        <input type="radio" name="residency" value="o" onclick="calcTuition('o')" /> Out-of-State <br />
        <input type="radio" name="residency" value="x" onclick="calcTuition('x')"/> International <br />
    <h2>Credits</h2>
    <h3>(enter your number of credits)</h3>
        <!--Text Box-->
        <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="numCredits" /><br />
        <!--Button to Calculate Tuition-->
        <input type="button" onclick="window.alert(calcTuition('i'))" value="Calculate Your Tuition" />
        </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I appreciate the advice, but that code didn't execute